# Multithreaded IllegalMonitorStateException

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, runtime-error, illegalstateexception

I'm writing a multithreaded tic tac toe program where a server is the connection between two clients. The server opens and waits for connections: the first client to connect is player X and the second is player O. Players have the ability to quit the game at any point, and once a client quits the other client resets its board and waits for a new connection. This part is working fine, but the issue is that once I spawn a new client I get the following errors:

> Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$Sync.tryRelease(ReentrantLock.java:149) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.release(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1300) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.unlock(ReentrantLock.java:439) at TicTacToeServer.processMessage(TicTacToeServer.java:329) at TicTacToeServer$Player.run(TicTacToeServer.java:498) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)

It appears that whichever thread has been closed is the one throwing this error. Player X is always whichever client connects first, so it is always thread 1 while player O is always thread 2. For the above error, I had closed player X and opened a new one (thread 3).

Each client window has a button allowing them to quit which uses an action listener, created as shown:

```
quitGame = new JButton("Quit");
  quitGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           System.out.println("Quit button was clicked!");
           displayMessage( "You have quit the game.\n" );
           output.format("Quit. " + myMark + "\n");
           output.flush();
           try
           {
               connection.close(); // close connection to client
               System.exit(0);
           } // end try
           catch ( IOException ioException )
           {
               ioException.printStackTrace();
               System.exit( 1 );
           } // end catch
       }
   });
  panel2.add( quitGame, BorderLayout.SOUTH ); // add button to panel
  add( panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER ); // add container panel
```

This then corresponds to the following code in the server:

```
else if (message.equals("Quit. X")) {
        //connection.close(player[PLAYER_X]);
        currentPlayer = PLAYER_X;
        displayMessage("\nPlayer X has ended the game.\n");
        players[1].send("Player X has ended the game.");
        players[1].send("Please wait for new player to connect.");

        players[(currentPlayer+1)%2].send("Restart.");
        players[currentPlayer].send("Restart.");
        for(int x = 0;x<board.length;x++)
        {
            board[x] = "";
            numRep[x] = 4;
        }// end for loop

        try // wait for connection, create Player, start runnable
        {
            players[ 0 ] = new Player( server.accept(), 0 );
            Player temp = players[0];
            players[1].send("New player has connected. Game on!");
            players[1].send("Please wait for your turn.");
            runGame.execute( players[0] ); // execute player runnable
        } // end try
        catch ( IOException ioException )
        {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
            System.exit( 1 );
        } // end catch

        //gameLock.lock();
        try // allow x to go first
        {
            players[ PLAYER_X ].setSuspended( false ); // resume player X
            otherPlayerConnected.signal(); // wake up player X's thread
        } // end try
        finally
        {
            gameLock.unlock(); // unlock game after signaling player X
        } // end finally
    } // end if
```

The lines specifically mentioned in the error are:

```
    gameLock.unlock(); // unlock game after signaling player X
```

which is shown in the finally block above and

```
if ( input.hasNextLine() )
        processMessage(input.nextLine()); // get message
```

Which is found in run() and calls processMessage, which processes messages sent by the client and is partially shown above.

I have been trying to mess around with closing the connection, input, output, etc. but I can't seem to get rid of this error. It does not affect the actual game, I'm assuming because the error is on the thread that is closed, but I'd still like to fix it. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

From the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#unlock--) of `ReentrantLock.unlock()`:

> If the current thread is not the holder of this lock then
>   IllegalMonitorStateException is thrown.

You need to aquire the lock before `unlock`.

Comment: The new thread/player or the one that is closed? Also how do I go about acquiring the lock? I thought it just existed for the game